# Execute wolfram command from java & j/link along with set of variables

Tags: kernel, java

I have been trying to execute some expression/formula which may have multiple variable, and I want to set values(like how we do on kernel command tool). We are using J/Link to connect kernel from java.

NOTE: having j/link jar on spring project and connecting wolframKernel on local.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. On [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ConnectAJavaProgramToTheWolframLanguage.html) tutorial page, can you repeat all the steps. If not, where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: particularly [Writing Java Programs That Use The Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/tutorial/WritingJavaProgramsThatUseTheWolframLanguage.html)

Comment: Example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8279901/879601